# About the HairTool add-on - I can't see the vertex lines at hair modeling

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm practicing the *HairTool* add-on and suddenly the lines disappeared. Maybe I pressed the wrong key...? Is there any way that I can see the lines or vertexes again without going to edit mode?

[image]

Comment: That appears to be a third-party addon, not part of Blender, so it would be best to ask questions about it from the original author. The docs seem to be [here](https://joseconseco.github.io/HairToolDocs_28/). Having said that' you seem to be in Material Preview mode rather than Solid mode (top-right icons in the 3D window) so you could try switching to solid mode and see if that helps.

Comment: oh sorry i will ask to hair tool add on , and yop even at solid mode it doesnt show, when i open new file and active hair tool the vertexes appear even at object mode only at my portfoli file doesnt work.. hmmm anyway thanks for the reply!

Comment: No problem. Most folks here (including me - I had to Google it!) probably haven't heard of that addon, let alone installed it so it's always best to try asking at the source first! :^)